why won't regexp substitute recognize \/ when substituting a section of the string
Hi:  Using regexp substitute in a perl script (linux)
Here's the code...
my $str="/a/bb/cc/config/12345/dd/ee/ff";
$str =~ s/\/config\/([^\/]+)\//theconfig/;
print "str: $str\n";

I want to replace "12345" with "theconfig".
The code returns...
str: /a/bb/cctheconfigdd/ee/ff

Notice how the forward slashed before and after "theconfig" are missing.  They were outside the parens in the regexp substitute statement, so I was surprised to see that they were missing.
This, however, works... (explicitely restore the missing fwd slashes in the sub string)
my $str="/a/bb/cc/config/12345/dd/ee/ff";
$str =~ s/\/config\/([^\/]+)\//\/theconfig\//;
print "str: $str\n";

Returns what I wanted...
str: /a/bb/cc/theconfig/dd/ee/ff

So why did the regexp substitute get rid of those forward slashes in the first case above ?

Why is that what you wanted? You said you only wanted to replace 12345, so shouldn't the result contain config/theconfig?

Why do you think it matters if they're outside the parentheses? You're not replacing the capture group, you're replacing the entire match.

Capture groups are used for copying parts of the match into the replacement, not limiting the replacement to that part of the input.

I think you meant that you wanted the string /a/bb/cc/config/theconfig/dd/ee/ff. At least if we are going on the logic that you only wanted to remove what was inside the parentheses (which is incorrect).

Your regexp matches the /config/ part of the input, and the / after the number, so you have to include them in the replacement string as well.
Also, when the pattern contains lots of / characters, use a different delimiter character so you don't have to keep escaping it.
There's no need for the capture group, you never reference it.
$str =~ s|/config/[^/]+/|/config/theconfig/|;

Result:
str: /a/bb/cc/config/theconfig/dd/ee/ff


Since you're keeping the prefix, \K is useful. s{/config/\K[^/]+/}{theconfig/}

The last slash is perhaps better left out, since it 1) is redundant, 2) will exclude paths that end with the target string. E.g. /foo/bar/config/12345

Both of those patterns matched the extra / characters. Everything you match is replaced (ignoring lookarounds). In the second one you added them back in the replacement side of s///. You said as much in the question yourself.
I might have written it like this, where I use the \K to ignore the parts of the pattern before it (a positive lookbehind, really), and then not match the last / because you don't want to replace it and the negated character class matches everything else:
my $str="/a/bb/cc/config/12345/dd/ee/ff";
$str =~ s| / \K config / [^\/]+ |theconfig|x;
print "str: $str\n";

This also uses an alternate delimiter | so I don't have to escape the / and I use the /x to spread out the pattern with insignificant whitespace.
Notice that I made the pattern that gets you the string you show at the end, which is not what you described before that. That is, one level of directory disappears:
str: /a/bb/cc/theconfig/dd/ee/ff

